# JQuery load at display page

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie on web technologies and particular on jQuery so my question can be stupid.

What I want is to call a particular file (using .get or .post jQuery) when I click on some link and also load that file into browser. Also, the browser address should point to that file. This is what I have tried:

```
$('#my_link').click(
    function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("index.php", function(data){
            $(document).html(data);
        });
    }
);
```

P.S.
I'm using .get/.post because I want to send some param. to that page (index.php), param. used to fill some fields.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you, to try `.load()` method instead. It also provides options for sending params.

Here is an example based on the question.

```
$('#my_link').click(function() {
   $('#mydiv').load ("index.php", { param1: val1, param2: val2 }, function) {
      alert('loaded');
   });
});
```

I would suggest to load the contents on a division rather than the document itself.

Comment: Thx for the answer but it doesn't solved my problem. I really want to load the document it self in browser

Comment: And you realize that, that the link with which you initiate the click will be removed once the load completes.

Comment: If you insists on loading it onto the document. Load it in the body. `$("body").load(..............`

Comment: I think what he wants is a hyperlink. So, technically no javascript is involved. Heh

Comment: Yes, indeed, $("body").load works and loads html code generated by index.php in current page. But I want to call/load index.php it self so the browser address points to index.php file